# Unable to initialize Pygame display, but only when running through tox

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.8, tox

I have the following, minimal test program.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
print(pygame.display.list_modes())
```

If I try to run this program via a Tox command, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(pygame.display.list_modes())
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

However, if I activate the virtual environment the tox command runs in and run the same program manually, it works as expected. I would expect both execution environments to be the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide both your full application code and your test? Maybe even a public GitHub repository? I have an idea and I'd like to try it on my system first

Comment: One difference between virtualenv and tox is that tox offers so-called isolated builds. It also does not use e.g. global environment variables except you whitelist them.

Comment: @J.G. All you should need to reproduce this is the above three-line program (saved as `test.py`) and [this tox.ini file](https://pastebin.com/aRHnrw4F). Put those two in an empty directory and try running `tox -e app`, `source .tox/py38/bin/activate`, and then `python3 test.py`.

Comment: Right, and a setup.py so tox can build the project. Just did that. I can reproduce the error.

Comment: I set the skipsdist flag in my tox.ini, at least for now, so I don't need a setup.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix the problem I needed to add a

```
passenv = DISPLAY
```

to my `[testenv]`.

As mentioned in the comment above, `tox` does an `isolated` build, and does not pass in `ENVIRONMENT` variables, except you whitelist them.

I am not super familiar with `pygame`, I just had a quick look in the source.

This works on my machine with Ubuntu - maybe it is different for your setup.

Comment: Glad I could help!